# How can I fix the problem regarding Cypress installation?

Tags: cypress

After I had to reinstall my Windows 10 I faced the problem of Cypress installation which I can't resolve. Before this moment it worked fine. But since the OS has been reinstalled I am not able to install Cypress in local folder any more. Whatever folder I try to use, Cypress is installed globally to c:\users\admin... folder. I tried to reinstall nodejs, clear npm cache, but nothing helped. Other packages can be installed properly, but not the Cypress. Did anybody face this problem and how it can be fixed?

Comment: It will help us to give you the answer if you can provide the error that you are receiving in command line when you are installing.... Also please try to delete the Cypress cache in your machine if it exists already from previous install.

Comment: @Srinu Kodi. Please, check description. There is nothing about errors. No errors at all. The only problem is that Cypress is installed globally but not in the folder I expect it to have.

Comment: Unbelievable, incredible, impossible. I have reinstalled Windows. I installed Node with those ... chocolatey. I used Node command line from the Node package for creating project folder and installing Cypress in it. The result is the same: instead of being installed to the project folder on drive E:\, the Cypress is installed to c:\users\admin which means installation globally